# Eliminate intrinsic padding/margin on <div> element

Tags: html, css-position, css

I'm working on a personal project, but I'm having some difficulty with a div, which has some styling that I can't seem to get around. It's a thin strip at the top of my user interface, where users have a few controls over what's shown on the screen. Pretty important to keep around (so deleting it isn't an option). In case it helps at all, I am using Eric Meyer's CSS Reset as a normalizer.

My problem is that the div element seems to have some intrinsic margin or padding that I can't seem to work around in my css. I've included a photo here for reference; the div is in green.

**I need to make that green div element thinner. It would help the layout a lot if I could move it closer to the top of the page. If you have any ideas or see something that I've missed, I would appreciate the help.**

[image: Green color is the div in question.]

I'm also including the html code for that content as follows:

```
<div class="new_entry_control_container">
    <p>You have <span class="credits">33 Credits</span> remaining.
        <span class="button">Add More Credits</span>
        <span class="button">Add More Items to Study List</span>

        <span class="pagination">&#60; 1 | 2 | 3 &#62;</span>
    </p>
</div>
```

As well as the CSS that applies here:

```
div.new_entry_control_container {
background-color: green;
max-width: 900px;
margin-left: auto;
margin-right: auto;}

div.new_entry_control_container p {
    text-align: center;}

.credits {
    color: #ffd400;}

.button {
    background-color: #ffd400;
    color: #3a0091;
    border: none;
    -webkit-border-radius: 6px;
    -moz-border-radius: 6px;
    border-radius: 6px;
    padding: 1px 8px 4px 8px;
    margin: 10px 0px 0px 3px;}

.pagination {
    margin-left: 25px;
    font-size: 17px;}
```

Comment: Something to be aware of is your `.button` is being used within spans, so you can't add top or bottom margins. There are no height type properties for inline elements. `display:block;` would make the margins work, but I recommend you use `<input type='button' />`. Of course my comment won't fix your problem, it's just a comment.

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out! I actually use the .button class a few other places, where that actually makes semantic sense, though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure if it's caused by the padding of parent element of that green bar. A workaround would be using negative "margin-top". And to make it thinner (assuming there would only be one line in that bar), use "height" combined with "line-height".

So the css might look like this

```
div.new_entry_control_container {
  background-color: green;
  max-width: 900px;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;

  margin-top: -10px;
  height: 18px; line-height: 18px;
}
```

Hope that helps.

Comment: It was the parent element! Actually it was the grandparent element, but thanks so much for pointing that out as a possibility. After looking at a screen for a while, my brain turns to mush.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
div.new_entry_control_container{
  padding:0;
  /* more CSS here */
}
.credits{
  padding:0; margin:0;
  /* other CSS  here */
}
```